# Receiving "No key available with this passphrase" with LUKS

Tags: debian, recovery, passphrase, luks

My laptop has an encrypted disk. After an `apt upgrade` and some hours later a force shutdown my passphrase doesn't decrypt my disk anymore.

I booted from a debian live usb stick and tried several things:

1. Can I decrypt the partition with my passphrase from the live os?
   [image]
   Answer: No.
2. Is it a problem with the keyboard layout?
   [image]
   Answer: No.
3. Is the partition still an encrypted one?
   [image]
   Answer: Yes it is and there is still one keyslot.
4. Is there a problem visible when looking at hexdump output?
   [image]
   Answer: No.
5. Is there maybe a problem visibile when looking at the hexdump configuration output?
   [image]
   Answer: Apart from the fact that a few blog posts say that everything above 1000 should be random characters: No.

---

I have no backup of my LUKS headers. My passphrase worked for over one year. **How can I access or rescue my data?**

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you've mistyped your password, as I had similar issue and blamed upgrade as well.

You can dump the header and try to brutal force it.

Following steps can help.

1. Confirm you've the right device:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup isLuks /dev/sda3 -v
   ```
2. Validate the header:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3
   ```
3. Try initial few passwords (consider adding `--debug` for more output):

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase /dev/sda3
   ```

   Or: `tcryptDump`, but shouldn't make any difference.
4. Consider to backup the header:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda3 --header-backup-file luksHeader.bin
   ```

   Alternatively run (replace count with *Payload offset* found in header dump):

   ```
    dd if=/dev/sda3 of=luksHeader.bin bs=512 count=4096
   ```

   You can also consider to backup the whole device using `dd`.
5. Use header file to try different passwords: (quicker than using the actual device)

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase luksHeader.bin
   ```

#### Brutal force

Having a small header file (as per above steps), you can try to brutal force it.

Assuming you know your original password, create the list of your potential password and their permutations in `passes.txt` (make the list unique by `sort -ou passes.txt`).

In shell, you can use the following script to try these combinations:

```
set -x
while read pass; do
  printf $pass | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase luksHeader.bin $@ && echo Success && break;
done < passes.txt
```

Notes:

- Since the files are small, you can scale it to many machines.
- Consider adding `--key-slot 0` for quicker checks.
- You can try to override `--pbkdf-force-iterations` (check how many there are in the header dump), but most likely it won't help.

#### Live CD

If you think that happened due to upgrade, use different [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download) Live CDs to use the above commands (Ubuntu 16, 18, 20 and so on).

Either boot from USB/CD, or install *VM VirtualBox* (Create Ubuntu VM, then load the ISO to boot from it).

To attach the physical device to *VM VirtualBox* (not recommended):

- In your newly created Ubuntu VM, attach Ubuntu's Live CD `.iso` file.
- Use `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk` command to create `.vmdk` files pointing to the real device. Attach these `.vmdk` into the VM (before starting it).
- If your user won't have access to these special devices during run, run `VirtualBoxVM` as root (also not recommended).

Final steps, copy the header file then test passphrases using older version of `cryptsetup` (`cryptsetup --version`).

#### Mounting

Once success, use these commands to mount the filesystem:

```
sudo cryptsetup isLuks /dev/sdb5 -v
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 newhd
sudo lvscan # Check if LVs are active.
sudo vgchange -ay # Activate LVs if not active.
sudo lvdisplay # List logical volumes (note the LV Path).
sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt
mount # List mounted filesystems.
xdg-open /mnt # Open in file explorer
```

Other useful commands:

```
sudo lvmdiskscan # List devices.
sudo vgdisplay # Display volume group information.
```

Comment: Will the brutal force script stop when it succeeds? How does this work. Why is the `&& Success && break` only executed when it succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too much time is gone by since you ask your question but:

> After an *apt upgrade* and some hours later a force shutdown my passphrase doesn't decrypt my disk anymore.

This shouldn't be a problem. I had to do that a lot on different devices. Yes, there is still a small possibility that this could damage something but LUKS is very robust.

> 1. Can I decrypt the partition with my passphrase from the live os?

Yes, that is definitely possible! Done it myself several times.

> 2. Is it a problem with the keyboard layout?

Possible. Write your passphrase in the terminal window to check if it is your password and then use the *cryptsetup* command. And rethink the possibility that you encrypted your drive with another layout. Try to remember how you encrypted it – during a fresh system install; on your working system over the terminal; with a tool; etc. .

> PASSPHRASE CHARACTER SET: Some people have had difficulties with this
> when upgrading distributions.  It is highly advisable to only use the 95
> printable characters from the first 128 characters of the ASCII table,
> as they will always have the same binary representation.  Other
> characters may have different encoding depending on system configuration
> and your passphrase will not work with a different encoding.

This quote is from [Gitlab cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

> 3. Is the partition still an encrypted one?

Yes it is. Make sure you use an up to date live cd with luks **version2**.

> I have no backup of my LUKS headers.

Doesn't look like you need a backup of the LUKS header.

EDIT: Some additional ideas:
How did you do the encryption? Is it a special partition like */home*?

- If the partition is your */home* and you did the encryption setup
  during the system install then you normally open your partition by
  your user password. But that is not the real passphrase for that
  partition because there will be a keyfile for opening your partition.
  That file is defined in /etc/crypttab.
- If you will be able to open your partition or setup a new one please make sure you

  - Setup not only one passphrase! Add another passphrase or a key-file in another keyslot.

> If you are sure you are entering the passphrase right, there is the
> possibility that the respective key-slot has been damaged.  There is no
> way to recover a damaged key-slot, except from a header backup...

This quote is also from [Gitlab cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions). Maybe you find more needed infos there.

- After the passphrases are done DO A HEADER-BACKUP! It's easy. The backup is small and most of the time you won't need it – I did not for the last 10 years and so many harddiks, usb-sticks, etc.!

  - Do NOT store the header-backup in your encrypted harddisk/partition!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new `master key` for your luks container

```sh
## Requires vim-common

cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3 --master-key-file <(dmsetup table --showkey /dev/mapper/foobar | awk '{print$5}' | xxd -r -p)
```

---

This will create a new passphrase for unlocking luks container and if this works then you can remove the previous passphrase and continue using it.