# LUKS2 Encryption NOT Accepting Correct Passphrase

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

**LUKS2 Encryption NOT Accepting Correct Passphrase, please help me to fix.**  I've the key saved in my "seahorse". It used to work flawlessly until a kernel/apt update.

I've attempted, without any luck-

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383788/luks-passphrase-doesnt-work
2. [Receiving "No key available with this passphrase" with LUKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960343/receiving-no-key-available-with-this-passphrase-with-luks)

Please seee below:

```
user@ubuntu-23-04:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --debug /dev/sdb1 home
# cryptsetup 2.6.1 processing "cryptsetup luksOpen --debug /dev/sdb1 home"
# Verifying parameters for command open.
# Running command open.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device /dev/sdb1.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/sdb1.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 [default][legacy]) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.6.1.
# Detected kernel Linux 6.2.0-23-generic x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdb1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:17
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdb1.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device /dev/sdb1
# Verifying locked device handle (bdev)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:3dc24e969106171243e1156279ccacd83b2698558da86ae48df187cb12ee70a5 (on-disk)
# Checksum:3dc24e969106171243e1156279ccacd83b2698558da86ae48df187cb12ee70a5 (in-memory)
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdb1
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:319aaf1f89bb0ae08aa7b83c48e0b791e549c1e49c58eadbea87a7384ac6937f (on-disk)
# Checksum:319aaf1f89bb0ae08aa7b83c48e0b791e549c1e49c58eadbea87a7384ac6937f (in-memory)
# Device size 500106788864, offset 16777216.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock released.
# PBKDF argon2id, time_ms 2000 (iterations 0), max_memory_kb 1048576, parallel_threads 4.
# Activating volume home using token (any type) -1.
# dm version   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-ioctl version 4.47.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status home  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
No usable token is available.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1: Error reading passphrase from terminal.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for /dev/sdb1.
```